# Basic question about math injectivity

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, functions

Suppose that $A:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^2$ and $B:\mathbb{R}^2\to \mathbb{R}^3$. Can we guarantee that either $A\circ B$ or $B\circ A$ is injective? Is it possible for either $A\circ B$ or $B\circ A$ to be injective?

**Answer?**
No it cannot be guaranteed as we may construct maps that are not injective. This is obvious in the $B \circ A$ case, perhaps a bit less obvious in the $A \circ B$ case. But, we may still construct a map that inputs an element of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and outputs $(0,0) \in \mathbb{R}^2$.

My other thoughts are as follows:
A map $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ may be injective if we we consider a map that takes an element, say, $(a,b)$ to $(0,a,b)$ and then to $(B(a),B(v))$. This map is injective if $B$ is.

On the other hand, I don't believe a map $\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ may be injective if the domain is all of $\mathbb{R}^3$. Obviously if it wasn't we could have a map taking $(0,a,b) \mapsto (a,b) \mapsto (0,A(a), A(b))$, but the domain here is just a plane..

Is this reasoning correct??

Comment: You should be more clear about your hypotheses. You did not say _anything_ about $A,B$, but from the name choice and the `linear-algebra` tag one might guess that they are supposed to be _linear_ maps. That hypothesis would make the question a lot simpler. _Without_ that hypothesis both $A$ and $B$ could be made to be bijections, but that would be more of a set-theory matter ($\Bbb R^2$ and $\Bbb R^3$ have the same cardinality, though not the same dimension).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen I apologize.. Yes, I believe they are assumed to be linear, although this was not explicitly given.

Answer (score 0):

$A$ can never be injective: its rank is at most $2$, which means, that its nullspace has dimension at least $1$. Hence, $B \circ A$  is never injective.

$B\circ A$ can be injective:
$$
A = \pmatrix{1& 0& 0 \\0&1&0}, \quad
B = A^T, \quad
A\circ B = AB = \pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.
$$
For given $B$ one can always find $A$ such that $A\circ B$ is not injective. All one has to do is to construct $A$  such that $im(B)\cap \ker(A)\ne\{0\}$.